# Combinations balls and three boxes

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider three boxes, each containing 10 balls
>   labelled $1,2,....,10$. Suppose one ball is
>   randomly drawn from each of the boxes and is denoted by $n_i$, where $i$ represents the box, $(i = 1, 2, 3).$ Then, the number of
>   ways in which the balls can be chosen such that $n_1<n_2<n_3$ is?

I tried doing this in different ways, but can't take the first step. I tried using multinomial theorem, but can't understand which terms to consider. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you take a ball in the middle, say it is $k$, then for the first one you have $k-1$ choises and for the third $10-k$ choises. So we have $$1\cdot 8 + 2\cdot 7 + 3\cdot 6 +  4\cdot 5 +   5\cdot 4 +6\cdot 3 +   7\cdot 2+8\cdot 1 = $$ $$= 2\cdot ( 1\cdot 8 + 2\cdot 7 + 3\cdot 6 +  4\cdot 5 )$$

$$= 2\cdot ( 8 + 14 + 18 +  20 )= 120$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to consider such cases, but the mistake I was doing was that I was trying to consider a ball from the first and last boxes. It didn't strike me to consider a ball from the middle box.

Comment: Ah extremely sorry for that. It is 2:45am here right now and in the midst of prepping for my sleep I'd forgotten about it.

Comment: No worry, thank you, have a nice sleep

Answer (score 6):

The number of ways to select the three balls is the same as the number of strictly ascending subsequences of length 3 taken from 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, which is the same as the number of subsets of size 3 taken from $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$, which is
$$\binom{10}{3} = 120$$